# LuaTeX and XeTeX reporting missing characters in Libertinus font

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, luatex, characters

Here is a MWE using Libertinus Serif typeface which has the inputed glyphs but XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX both reports: "Missing character: There is no ➌ in font Libertinus Serif":

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
This char is missing: (^^^^278d)\par
This is also missing: (^^^^278c)\par
This char is not: (^^^^24ea)\par
\end{document}
```

My output is:

[image: lualatex output]

And my log file reports:

```
Missing character: There is no ➍ in font Libertinus Serif/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ➌ in font Libertinus Serif/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;!
```

But, as you can see below those glyphs are present in Libertinus Serif typeface:

[image: charmap]

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Just that the fonts don't have the glyph. No font is required to have the whole glyph set. Software that shows character tables often do font substitutions.

Comment: Character maps are not a reliable source for the glyphs of a font, quite often the OS pulls in some other fonts to fill up the map.

Comment: @egreg "Software that shows character tables often do font substitutions". Sorry, I was not aware of that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you know any (free) reliable tool in order to check glyphs in a font?

Comment: If you want to know if a glyph exists run  for example`otfinfo -g libertinussans-regular.otf | grep uni27`.  With `grep uni278` you'll get no output: no glyphs from `uni2780->uni278f`

Comment: After all, it's not so surprising that Libertinus Serif doesn't provide sans serif digits.

Comment: Although the missing output from otfinfo above is for `libertinussans-regular.otf`,  a sans-serif font...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontfamily\LibSans{Libertinus Sans}

\begin{document}
    This char is present: (^^^^2779)\par
    This is also present: (^^^^277a)\par
    This char is present: (^^^^24ea)

\LibSans
    This char is present: (^^^^2779)\par
    This is also present: (^^^^277a)\par
    This char is present: (^^^^24ea)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting back the correct **serif** dingbat codes! But I really need those sans-serif negative circled digits glyphs coded from U+278A through U+2792. Unfortunately it seems that they are not present in Libertinus Serif (or Sans). Anyway, the serif version you've posted could be an alternative to others.

Comment: The Sans Serif dingbats are at the same position! See edited answer

Comment: I meant the sans-serif version of those dingbat symbols, not the font itself. Check [here](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=NEGATIVE) that "circled sans-serif" codes follows right after the serif version. Note also that, comparing your output above, both symbols are equal (i.e. serif'ed).

Comment: Then simply use a font which has such symbols, eg: `\newfontfamily\LibSans{ArialUnicodeMS}`